# How to create name value pair array in yii2

Tags: arrays, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am trying to create an `Array` in `yii2` in following format

```
[
  ['id'=>'2', 'name'=>'ABC'],
  ['id'=>'3', 'name'=>'DEF']
]
```

So far i have tried to use `ArrayHelper` class but if i `map` using it than it removes the `key` part from the array,i need to create the array in exact this format

```
$data = User::find()
        ->where(['id' => $id])
        ->orderBy('id DESC')
        ->all();
```

As you know after this code i get the data in `ActiveRecord` format so i need to convert them to `id` and `name` array only,i dont need any other data.

I tried doing this

```
 $data2 = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'name');
```

But returns the data in following format

```
[
  ['2'=>'ABC'],
  ['3'=>'DEF']
]
```

I have tried this as well

```
$data = MainCategory::find()->select('id,name')
 ->where(['id' => $id])
  ->orderBy('id DESC') 
 ->asArray()->all();
```

But its returning the array in following format

```
[
  '0' =>
      [
       'id'=>'2', 
       'name'=>'ABC'
      ],
  '1' =>
      [
       'id'=>'3', 
       'name'=>'DEF'
      ]
]
```

How can i achive `key` and `value` format in `yii2`?

Comment: Returning array is the same as you mentioned in the very beginning. What's the current problem?

Comment: @arogachev when i fire the query it returns the array in the last format i posted in question but i want to achieve the format which is on top,without grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch data as array like this:

```
$data = User::find()
    ->select('id, name')
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->orderBy('id DESC')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

To create plain KEY => VALUE array use `column()` method:

```
$data = User::find()
    ->select(['name', 'id'])
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->orderBy('id DESC')
    ->asArray()
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->column();
```

First selected column [name] will be returned as a VALUE.